# Finding an area of a triangle inside a square

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find area of the shaded region. The length of the side of the square is 10.

The small bars on the line segments indicate they are of the same length of 5.

[image]

I think it should be slightly over 25 but have not been able to find the exact value.

Could anybody help me with this problem?

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think it should be just over 25?

Comment: I can see that the upper corner is a little bit above the vertical line, so the area is a bit more.

Comment: Do you know [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem)? One way can be to put another copy of the square to the right, and extend the diagonal line that goes to the midpoint of the right side into that second square. The area of the triangle formed by this line, the top sides and the other diagonal line departing from the lower left vertex is easy. The shades triangle's area is in the proportion as the first diagonal line that we extended is divided by those triangles. That proportion can be computed using Menelaus' theorem.

Comment: The ends of the lines are supposed to be at the midpoints of the sides?

Answer (score 2):

I would use similar triangles.
[image]

The area of $\triangle AGE$ is the area of $\triangle ABE$ from which you subtract the area of $\triangle ABG$

$$A_{AGE}=\frac12 AB\cdot EI-\frac12 AB\cdot GH$$

You know $AB=EI=10$, so the only thing you need to calculate is $GH$. Let's call $GH=h$ amd $AH=x$. Then $HB=10-x$. $\triangle ABF\sim\triangle AHG$ so $$\frac h 5=\frac x{10}$$
Then $\triangle BEI\sim\triangle BGH$ so $$\frac h{10}=\frac{10-x}5$$
Find $h$ from these two equations and plug it into the formula for the area.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much geometry, but you could easily calculate
$$
\int_0^52x-\frac{x}{2}dx+\int_5^{8}20-2x-\frac{x}{2}dx=30
$$
[image]

The blue line is $y=2x$, the orange one is $y=20-2x$ and the red one $y=x/2$

Answer (score 0):

[image: Illustration, splitting the figure to its constituent parts]

There are four basic approaches here:

1. Direct area integral
2. General triangle area after determining the location $(8, 4)$ of the third point (where the hypotenuses of triangles C and D intersect)
3. Right triangle area after determining the triangle is a right triangle, and then calculating the two leg lengths
4. By splitting the figure to its constituent triangles, and observing that the area of $A$ is $A = B - C + E$.

Here are the short descriptions of each approach:

1. The figure consists of three line segments.  If we choose origin as the lower left corner, then the bottommost line segment is $y = \frac{1}{2} x$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 10$, and the two top line segments are $y = 2 x$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 5$, and $y = 20 - 2 x$ from $x = 5$ to $x = 10$.  The third and the first intersect at $y = \frac{1}{2} x = 20 - 2 x$:

   $$\begin{aligned}
     \frac{1}{2}x &= 20 - 2 x \\
     \iff \quad \frac{5}{2}x &= 20 \\
     \iff \quad \quad x &= \frac{2}{5} 20 = 8 \\
     \end{aligned} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

   and therefore at $y = 4$.  Thus, the integral is

   $$\begin{aligned}
   A &= \left( \int_{0}^{5} \left( 2 x - \frac{1}{2} x \right) d x \right) +
        \left( \int_{5}^{8} \left( 20 - 2 x - \frac{1}{2} x \right) d x \right) \\
   ~ &= \int_{0}^{5} \frac{3}{2} x d x + \int_{5}^{8} \left( 20 - \frac{5}{2} x \right) d x \\
   ~ &= \left[ \frac{3}{4} x^2 + \right]_0^5 + \left[ 20 x - \frac{5}{4} x^2 \right ]_5^8 \\
   ~ &= \left( \frac{75}{4} - 0 \right) + \left( 80 - \frac{275}{4} \right) \\
   ~ &= \frac{75 - 0 + 320 - 275}{4} = \frac{120}{4} = 30 \\
   \end{aligned}$$
2. If we choose lower left corner as origin, then the hypotenuse of triangle $C$ is $y = \frac{1}{2}x$, and the hypotenuse of triangle $D$ is $y = 20 - 2 x$.  These intersect at $y = 8$, $x = 4$, as shown in $\eqref{1}$ above.

   Thus, we have a triangle with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(5, 10)$, and $(8, 4)$.  The two edge vectors starting at origin are therefore $(+5, +10)$ and $(+8, +4)$ (where the plus signs are just a reminder to us humans that these vectors are displacements, whereas the vertex vectors are positions).

   The area of a triangle is half the magnitude of the two-dimensional analog of the vector cross product of any two edges starting at the same vertex.  That is, if the edge vectors are $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$, the area is $\frac{a d - b c}{2}$.  Thus,

   $$A = \left\lvert \frac{ 5 \times 4 - 10 \times 8}{2} \right\rvert = 30$$
3. Noting that triangles C and D are the same, just rotated by $90°$, and both are right triangles, we see that their hypotenuses form a right triangle.  This means that triangle A itself is a right triangle too.

   (In fact, due to the same argument, E is a right triangle too, so that all triangles in the figure are right triangles.)

   Using $\eqref{1}$ we know that the vertex with the right angle is at $(8, 4)$.  Therefore, the lengths $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ of the two legs are

   $$\begin{aligned}
   \ell_1 &= \sqrt{8^2 + 4^2} = \sqrt{80} \\
   \ell_2 &= \sqrt{(8 - 5)^2 + (10 - 4)^2} = \sqrt{45} \\
   \end{aligned}$$

   and the area of the triangle is half the product of the two leg lengths,
   $$A = \frac{1}{2} \ell_1 \ell_2 = \frac{\sqrt{80} \sqrt{45}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{80 \times 45}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3600}}{2} = 30$$
4. We know the square side length is $10$, and therefore area $100$.

   The area of triangle C is one quarter of the area of the square, therefore $C = 25$.  Triangle D is the same as triangle C, just rotated, so $D = 25$ also.  Triangle B is either half of the area of the square (because area of a triangle is half the product of its base and its height, $10 \times 10 / 2 = 50$), or the area of the square minus twice the area of triangle D, $100 - 2 \times 25 = 50$, so $B = 50$.

   Because $C$ and $D$ are the same triangle, just rotated by $90°$, their hypotenuses form an $90°$ degree angle too.  Therefore, triangle $E$ is a right triangle.  Because $E$ has two same angles as triangle $D$ (the acute and the right angles), the two triangles are similar.

   Since the area of the target figure is $A = B - C + E = 50 - 25 + E$, we now know that $A = 25 + E$.

   There are various ways to calculate the area of triangle $E$.

   We might observe that the length of the hypotenuse of $D$ is $h_D = \sqrt{10^2 + 5^2} = \sqrt{125}$, and the length of the hypotenuse of $E$ is $h_E = 5$.  Because scaling edge lengths by $x$ scales the area by $x^2$, we have

   $$E = \left( \frac{h_e}{h_D} \right)^2 D = \left( \frac{5}{\sqrt{125}} \right)^2 D = \frac{25}{125} D = \frac{1}{5} D$$

   and since $D = 25$, $E = D/5 = 25/5 = 5$.

   Or, we might use $\eqref{1}$ and note that the legs of $E$ are $\sqrt{2^2+4^2}=\sqrt{20}$ and $\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{5}$, and calculate the area as half the product of the leg lengths,

   $$E = \frac{\sqrt{20}\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{100}}{2} = 5$$

   In any case, we have $A = B - C + E = 50 - 25 + 5 = 30$.

Comment: If someone with the necessary reputation could edit this post to embed the illustration, I'd appreciate it; I do not have the reputation for the image to be visible.

Comment: You can also use Heron's formula, once you have the length of the sides